# How to capture Back button event in JS code using Framework7-React?

Tags: reactjs, html-framework-7

I need to capture back button event in my code for specific page only. As I am using Framework7 NavBar react component, I cannot find a place where I can override/capture the back event.

I am referring framework7-react for IOS app development and I have put 'Back' Link as in documentation. Framework7 version 4.3.1

They are providing 'backLink' property for the Navbar but how can I capture a event in my JS code?

This is the link for Framework7 React documentation for Navigation bar.
https://framework7.io/react/navbar.html

Comment: This is Nav bar code I am using <Navbar title="View Details" backLink="Back"></Navbar>

Comment: You need to use backLink button for other page? Is I understood Your question right?

Comment: Not really, I need to do something else in my JavaScript code when user click back button. There is no element/css class I can capture the click event on Back link as the Navbar is implemented as <Navbar title="View Details" backLink="Back"></Navbar>

Comment: In this case You can create Your custom button. In Framework 7 - React You can find NavLeft component or in Navbar You can create Button or any other element and give them `<a href="#" slot="nav-left">Left Link</a>` - like this: https://framework7.io/react/navbar.html#navbar-slots look here properly. Good luck :)

Comment: @Robert Thanks a lot for the guidance!. I was able to make it work with Navbar Slots. I posted answer in detail in case it will help others

Answer (score 1):

With @Robert Hovhannisyan's guidance, I have managed to make it work. What I did was expanding Navbar implementation adding NavBar Slots.

```html
<Navbar title="Home">
  <a href="#" className="home-back" slot="nav-left">Back</a>
  <a href="#" slot="nav-right">Next</a>
  <div>Home</div>
</Navbar>
```

After that I was able to catch onClick event on "Back" link using css class "home-back"

Hope this helps someone.